# VSS to TFS Solution Issue

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

we've moved a multi-project solution from VSS to TFS 2012.  We've removed all of the *scc* files from the solution, but when opening the solution we still receive error messages about the project missing source control files.  When opening the solution from the TFS Source Control Explorer, VS2010 gives the error message, but opens the solution under source control.  When opening the solution directly from the local .sln file, it gives the error messages and opens the solution without source control.

Any ideas?  Are there updates we need to make to the csproj and sln files to remove references to VSS?

Answer (score 3):

As is said in the previous answer, you could remove VSS bindings from menu
 
File->Source Control->Change Source Control... and then click Unbind option. 
If you can't open the solution on Visual Studio you could solve this by editing the solution file and projects files as well as deleting the .scc files.

Delete the .scc files.

Open .sln file:
You need to remove entire section **GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl)**
example:

```
GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 
        SccLocalPath0 = .
        SccProjectUniqueName1 = 
        SccLocalPath1 = .
        SccProjectFilePathRelativizedFromConnection1 = 
        SccProjectUniqueName2 = 
        SccLocalPath2 = .

EndGlobalSection
```

Under the section (if exists):

```
ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
```

removed the following 4 lines:

```
SccProjectName = ""
    SccAuxPath = ""
    SccLocalPath = "."
    SccProvider = "MSSCCI:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe"
```

save the .sln file

For each project file (.vbproj, .csproj, ...)
Remove following tags:

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

save the project file.
Now try to open the solution with visual studio, the SourceControl Binding should it be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Use File->Source Control->Change Source Control.